# Alternate way to perform 1 - X?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I want to take the C expression y = 1 - X and make it into MIPS compiled language.
Assume that x = $s0 and y = $s1

```
addi $s1, 1, -$s0
```

Is there an alternative way?

Comment: There's always `-~-X`.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY: On 2's complement architectures. But the C standard does not enforce this representation.

Comment: Since `addi $s1,1,-$s0` is _not_ a valid mips instruction, are you just looking for the (i.e. _any_) valid ordinary sequence (vs. doing two's complement equivalents to using `sub`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
li $s1, 1
subu $s1, $s1, $s0
```

Comment: Since the expression is `y = 1 - x`, the old value of `y` will be _replaced_. So, no need to use `$t0`. It can be replaced with `$s1`

Comment: That's right. It could as well be
li $s1, 1; 
subu $s1, $s0

Comment: If you edit, I'll upvote as I think this is _the_ answer (see my top comment).

Comment: Close. But, you regressed slightly because `subu` is 3 arg

Comment: It can be perfectly reduced into 2 arguments, see this:
See this:
http://www.imagebam.com/image/807899506179029

subu $s1, $s0
can be interpreted as s1 -= s0 or s1 = s1 - s0;

Comment: Maybe for a real assembler, but both the `spim` and `mars` simulators [which OP is probably using] flag it. The link is a trace output, so it may be playing loose with the disassembly. Also, to me, it's less clear. And harder to edit if the registers had to change [or change back again ;-)]

Answer (score 2):

Yes. First negate `$s0` as a twos complement number:

```
nor  $t0, $s0, $zero # flip bits of X, store in $t0
addi $t0, $t0, 1     # add one to $t0

addi $s1, $t0, 1     # now, add 1 to -X, store result in $s1
```

You could also combine two steps into one, and use one less register. This is a little less clear, though:

```
nor  $s1, $s0, $zero
addi $s1, $s1, 2
```